# Stretch nested div width to width of container?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: Desired Output]

Hi StackOverflow,

How can I get my code to resemble my desired output. I basically want a div resembling a card with a nested div that takes on the full width of the card div (without the padding)
Not having any luck so far with the following code:

CSS:

```
.card {overflow:hidden;padding:5px;}
.innerStripe {position:absolute; left:0; right:0; background-color:red; color:white;} overflow:hidden;}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="card" style="col-md-12">
   <h1>Title Text</h1>
   <div class="innerStripe">Bar Text</div>
   <p>Paragraph text...</p>
</div>
```

See JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/CkVLn/ (can't get paragraph to show after the stripe)

Comment: check your css, it do have incorrect format. can you make a fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gbgB4/37/)

Forget position, the simple way is to use `margin`. Always give negative margins in this kind of situation. Give negative margin from both side same as the `border-width`

Css will be :

```
.card { padding:0px;  border:5px solid #CCC; }
.card * { padding:0px 30px; }
.innerStripe { margin:0px -5px; background-color:red; color:white; padding:0px 35px; }
```

Comment: Its my pleasure always :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `absolute position` from your div.

**CSS**

```
 .card {overflow:hidden; width:100px;border:1px solid black;position:relative;}
 .innerStripe {background-color:red; color:white; overflow:hidden;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CkVLn/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Updated your fiddle with a simple solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/9DcBX/

Remove the padding from the outer div.

Also, remove the position:absolute and left and right attributes from innerstripe

```
.innerstripe{
width:100%;
background-color:red; 
color:white;
}
```